# SettingsActivity questions

Tags: android, android-preferences

I recently started developing in Android (using Android Studio 3.1.3) and learned about `SettingsActivity` the other day. I used this template to create the settings I need for my app and it does a very nice job. However, I have some questions:

I see no way to customize the settings pages created by the template. I wouldn't mind playing with the background colours or maybe making the fonts a bit bigger. How do I do that?

I see no navigation controls in the settings pages created by the template (pref_general, pref_data_sync, pref_notifications and pref_headers). The only way I can find to go back to my app is by pressing the back button on the bezel of my phone.

Is there any other way to get "up" navigation to take me back to my app? I thought about adding a toolbar and setting the "up" navigation on that but the preference XML files don't look like ordinary XML files and don't seem to follow the normal rules; I got error messages when I tried to write toolbar XML instructions in one of the preference XML files.

Comment: Can you post code to help us to more understand what you want. Because they many questions in one question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually, I just used the SettingsActivity template in Android Studio and then adjusted the code in pref_general.xml until it had the settings I needed. But if you simply choose that template for one of your projects and don't change it in the slightest, you'd have perfectly good code to look at. My changes don't matter in the slightest. I'm just wondering how I would add an "up" button to the code generated by the template and change font sizes and background colours (if I want to).

Answer (score 0):

One thing which you must understand is that, SettingsActivity has been included in Android to ease the process of Settings. So you don't need to complicate it by modulating the fonts or size of text. It's good to use as it is. Although the color of the textcan surely be changed by making some changes in xml code of the same.

Secondly, navigation is not required in SettingsActivity at all. Have you ever seen navigation in any of the application in Settings field? Answer is no. So keep things simple.